# How to add standard field lookup filter in to the change set?

Tags: deployment, change-set, lookup-filter

I need to add lookup filter modification in to the change set which is done to a standard field in the Contact object. Is that possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it is possible to move custom lookup filters in standard objects between orgs with change sets. It should be possible using the Metadata API though, since the `CustomField` metadata has a field called `LookupFilter`, which has `FilterItem`s and `FilterOperation`s inside.

From the documentation:

> ## CustomField
>
> Represents the metadata associated with a field. Use this metadata type to create, **update**, or delete custom field definitions on standard, custom, and external objects or **standard field definitions on standard objects**. This type extends the Metadata metadata type and inherits its fullName field.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customfield.htm